# Sorting by Date in mongodb pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have db entry like below i want to sort by added_on but its giving error . Do we have some way to sort the date in this format or is is suggested to use some other format of storing date

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d1a9dc1170b35414a180d7"),
    "c" : "TPCG",
    "modified_on" : ISODate("2016-09-08T18:11:40.150Z"),
    "euuu" : "5",
    "owner" : null,
    "added_on" : ISODate("2016-09-08T18:11:40.150Z")
}
```

Error

```
> db.testjobs.find({'add_on':{$lte: ISODate("2016-09-08T18:11:40.150Z")}}).sort('added_on',-1).limit(3)
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue sort must be object or array",
    "code" : 17287
}

>db.testjobs.find().sort('added_on',-1)
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue sort must be object or array",
    "code" : 17287
```

Comment: Your question is tagged with pymongo, but the code you show appears to be JS running in the shell?

Comment: it's the output of mongodb terminal, my sort failed on terminal it self so didnlt proceed for pymongo but incase u can share thoughts for pymongo its well n good

Comment: I believe it's caused by wrong syntax of you input....

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a minor issue which you overlooked :)

First statement contained a filter 'add_on' instead of 'added_on'. 
Both contained sort('added_on', -1') this should be sort('added_on' : -1)

```
db.testjobs.find({'added_on':{$lte: ISODate("2016-09-08T18:11:40.150Z")}}).sort('added_on' : -1).limit(3)})

db.testjobs.find().sort('added_on':-1)
```

Both are working here.